# StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN caused by ChannelClosedException

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

We are seeing these errors on the client side sporadically.

```
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: channel closed
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:532)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:434)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:398)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at io.grpc.netty.Utils.statusFromThrowable(Utils.java:166)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.onConnectionError(NettyClientHandler.java:474)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.onError(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:641)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionEncoder.writeHeaders(DefaultHttp2ConnectionEncoder.java:225)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DecoratingHttp2FrameWriter.writeHeaders(DecoratingHttp2FrameWriter.java:53)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.StreamBufferingEncoder.writeHeaders(StreamBufferingEncoder.java:157)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.StreamBufferingEncoder.writeHeaders(StreamBufferingEncoder.java:141)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.createStream(NettyClientHandler.java:543)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.write(NettyClientHandler.java:312)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:708)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:791)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:701)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1026)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:288)
    at io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue$AbstractQueuedCommand.run(WriteQueue.java:174)
    at io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue.flush(WriteQueue.java:112)
    at io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue.access$000(WriteQueue.java:32)
    at io.grpc.netty.WriteQueue$1.run(WriteQueue.java:44)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:515)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:955)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:863)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1378)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:708)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:791)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:701)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameWriter.writeHeadersInternal(DefaultHttp2FrameWriter.java:528)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameWriter.writeHeaders(DefaultHttp2FrameWriter.java:268)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2OutboundFrameLogger.writeHeaders(Http2OutboundFrameLogger.java:60)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionEncoder.writeHeaders(DefaultHttp2ConnectionEncoder.java:208)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:58)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:928)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:356)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:895)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1383)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.sendPingFrame(NettyClientHandler.java:646)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.write(NettyClientHandler.java:318)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Both the server and the client run in Kubernetes with the server being a ClusterIP service. The client's channel builder looks like this:

```
NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("some-service", 8090)
                .nameResolverFactory(DnsNameResolverProvider.asFactory())
                .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin")
                .idleTimeout(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .usePlaintext();
```

The client sends requests in a burst of 4-5 (concurrently using project-reactor) every 5 minutes. We see failures happening once or twice a day. We have tried setting both keepAlive and idleTimeout on separate occasions but nothing seems to be working. We have retries defined for `UNAVAILABLE` and `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` status codes but not `UNKNOWN` since that could mean retrying on potentially non-retriable errors. Is there a way to fix this on the client side without having to retry on `UNKNOWN` errors?

Client gRPC version: 1.20.0
Server gRPC version: 1.20.0
Netty Version: 4.1.39.Final

Comment: What sort of environment is this deployed to? If there are intermediary proxies between the client and server? It's possible that they're terminating the TCP connection after some timeout. In general, it's not reasonable to expect that a TCP connection involving any elements not under your control will last forever. You'll need to handle the case that  the connection dies once in a while due to factors outside of your control. FWIW, a 12-24 hour TCP connection is actually pretty good.

Comment: Hello Richard, as I mentioned in my question, both the server and the client run in Kubernetes with the server being a ClusterIP service which I believe does its own load balancing. The client's channel builder has a round robin load balancing policy configured as well. 

We have not seen the error since we removed the load balancing policy. Having said that, the error occurs out of the blue and as we could not reproduce it predictably, it is hard to say whether the removal of the load balancing policy fixed the problem or not.